# Use Weka in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, artificial-intelligence, weka

I have been trying unssuccessfully so far to install the package for Weka (Weka 0.1.3)found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/weka) on my Windows computer. My problem is that each time I try to run the setup or use the command:

```
pip install -U https://github.com/chrisspen/weka/tarball/master
```

I get an assertion error saying that

> "Weka JAR file /usr/share/java/weka.jar not found. Ensure the file is
>   installed or update your environment's WEKA_JAR_PATH to only include
>   valid locations."

Indeed I do not have this file, but how should I get it? I am not sure if I missed anything regarding the installation, at least I did what's specified on the official webpage.

Any suggestions? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a wrapper package you need to install Weka, (presumably for windows), as well - it is [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/weka/files/weka-3-7-windows-x64/) you may also have to upgrade or install java.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I also did that, so I have installed Weka 3.6.10, but it's a desktop application. Thought I can use it directly from Python somehow..

Comment: Try downloading and unzipping the zip format - then set WEKA_JAR_PATH to point to where you unzipped it.

Answer (score 1):

To run in Windows:

- Add weka.jar, libsvm.jar, wlsvm.jar to `C:\usr\share\java` directory (libsvm.jar and wlsvm.jar can be found at http://www.cs.iastate.edu/~yasser/wlsvm/)
- run `pip install -U https://github.com/chrisspen/weka/tarball/master`
- When you try to run classifiers you will get a classpath error. To solve this error edit installed file `<Python install dir>\Lib\site-packages\weka\classifiers.py`
- Line 33: Change `for _cp in CP.split(':'):` to `for _cp in CP.split(os.pathsep):`
- Line 286: Change `close_fds=True` to `close_fds=sys.platform != "win32"`